# Weak and strict dominance

Tags: game-theory

Im just seeking for confirmation, is it OK to say that :
"A strictly dominant strategy is a weakly dominant strategy too"?
This would be usefull because for IEWDS we can eliminate strictly dominant strategies first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you mention IEWDS, I presume by "dominant" you actually mean "dominated".

Any strictly **dominated** strategy would satisfy the condition defining weakly **dominated** strategies and hence be called such. And yes, strictly dominated strategies can (and should) be eliminated in the process of IEWDS.

The possible typo notwithstanding, any strictly **dominant** strategy would satisfy the condition defining weakly **dominant** strategies and hence be called such.